# R cran Subset text lines based on keywords

Tags: r, string

I have a linux text file (log file) that I read from the R studio in windows.

I have installed the `enc` package to use read_lines_enc function that can read UTF-8 files.

So far so good.

After reading the file in R I get back the following structure

```
str(LogFail)
# 'utf8' chr [1:1321]
```

that is an array of characters (each row is a line from the text file I was reading)

I want now to find a way to pick the line numbers that contain any of specific set of keywords for example:  `c("fail", "error")`. After picking those lines numbers I want to keep two or three sentences before and after of this line (trying to capture that way the reason the error appeared).

Can you help me with these two subproblems?

To summarize:

1. First find the line numbers that contain any word of a set of specific keywords.
2. Then from the initial file keep few lines before and after the line numbers as these were collected at step 1.

A recommendation on libraries that one can use will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.
Regards
Alex

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keywords<-c("fail","error")
wordrange<-2 # Number of lines before and after identified ones to grab
KWind<-grep(paste0(keywords,collapse="|"),LogFail) # identify the indexes of lines with keywords
# ** (see below)
grablist<-as.vector(sapply(KWind, function(x) (x-wordrange):(x+wordrange)))
grablist<-unique(grablist[grablist>0 & grablist<=length(LogFail)]) # remove possible subzero cases, overlaps and indexes larger than the actual LogFail vector
LogFail[grablist] # Your desired list
```

For improved readability, you might consider adding the following line where I put the **:

```
LogFail[KWind]<-paste("*", LogFail[KWind])
```

This will make the actual lines with the keywords stand out more clearly.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not vote. But your reply is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers. You can't vote yet, but as the asker, you can accept an answer (and you even gain reputation for it!)